# Getting other people to bake with you

Tags: baker

I do not have 8,000 coins yet.  How do I attract the attention of other coin holders to bake their coins for them?  How do I apply to become a baker once I have the required 8,000 coins?

Answer (score 1):

In regards to the first question, on how to attract the attention of other coin holders, I think it is simpler to instead delegate your coins to a baker. There are many such services, you can find a list [here](https://mytezosbaker.com/).

For the second question, that is, how to apply to become a baker once you've acquired a roll. For this, see the tezos documentation [here](http://tezos.gitlab.io/introduction/howtorun.html). It amounts to running a command with tezos-client, that registers your key as a delegate and then running the baker and endorser daemons.

Answer (score -1):

Feel free to delegate to Tezos-Japan

https://tezosjapan.info/?page_id=184

When smart-contracts are available that allow for baking bond contracts then we can work together.

Cheers!